# Can't Delete Function Call

Tags: python, syntax-error

This question is just out of general curiosity. I've just noticed it when working on my current project (surprisingly I haven't came across before today).

Take this code:

```
List = ["hi","stack","over","flow","how","you","doing"]
del List(len(List)-1)
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: can't delete function call
```

I don't understand why you aren't allowed to delete an index of a list by referencing a call to a function? Do I just shut up and accept you can't do it or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

I apologise if there is an easy answer to this but either Google is getting less helpful or this is so blatantly obvious I need help.

Comment: It's a bad idea to call a list-instance `List`, you could easily confuse one for the other.

Comment: Please fix the title to this question. You're intent is not to delete a function call but to *use* a function call with delete.  Not "delete function call" but "Use del with a function call" or something more clear and more descriptive of what you're trying to do.

Comment: "Delete the result of a function call", perhaps.

Comment: The title represents the error. Usually when I encounter an error, I simply paste the error into google to see what I get back. Hence why I named it this. I figured you might have worked that out.

Comment: Congratulations, we're the first hit on Google for "can't delete function call".

Comment: :) Excellent! Should anyone be quite as stupid as me, they'll end up here to admire our stupidity!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You meant to delete the last element of the list, not somehow call `List` as a function:

```
del List[len(List)-1]
```

Python's `del` statement must take specific forms like deleting a variable, list[element], or object.property. These forms can be nested deeply, but must be followed. It parallels the assignment statement -- you'll get a similar syntax error if you try to assign to a function call.

Of course, what you *really* want in this case is

```
del List[-1]
```

which means the last element of the list, and is way more Pythonic.

Comment: +1: Delete might work with a call to a function, but the example is obviously an object named List.   Not a function  named List.

Comment: Nope, it's a syntax error regardless. The simplest form "del x" means delete the name "x". "del x[y]" and "del x.y" send various messages to the object x with y as the parameter. While you might come up with a valid use case to define "del x(y)", it's not Python.

Answer (score 5):

You are calling a function `List()` when you should be indexing a list, `List[]`.

In Python, Round parenthesis, `()`, are used to call functions, while square brackets, `[]` are used to index lists and other sequences.

Try:

```
del List[len(List) - 1]
```

or even better, use the fact that Python allows negative indexes, which count from the end:

```
del List[-1]
```

Also, you might want to make the list's name not so close to the built-in `list` type name, for clarity.

Comment: List[len(List) - 1] is not "pythonic", you want to do List[-1] as jleedev suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed. However, you are using the wrong syntax.  Correct syntax is:

```
del List[-1]
```

Notice that the "len(List) part is useless.